# Conflict Update Model (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, token, updates, conflict

My first question is not really specific to rails, but more general about good practices.

Let's suppose that I have an API with only one Model : Post. And few records of it.

- A first client who modify a specific Post record but doesn't have services to call the API. So he will store the modifications locally until getting services.
- A second client, who modify the same record, but able to call the API to modify this record on the server side, while the first client didn't push the local modification yet.

Back to the first client, when he reached services. So, he is gonna try to push the local modifications stored.
Two scenarios:

1. Should I prevent his push modification since the second client already push modifications closer in time ?
2. Should I still push the modifications from the first client and override the modifications of the second client ?

If the first answer, how can I manage that ?
I was thinking about an "**update_token**" or **timestamp** that I send with the modification request. The Server check if the **token** or **timestamp** match then modify the record and update the **token**/**record**.
Is that a good practice ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't have services to call the API" ? You mean - no network ?

Comment: @PamioSolanky Suppose that the client is an iOS application. I'm storing the modifications if the device doesn't have services, and can't push it. In order to push it when the network will be available.

Comment: So both these devices are modifying the same record ?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same record!

Comment: 1. Yes, you generally want to avoid overwriting new changes.
2. Yes still allow a user to attempt a save, but use locking to know if that save can take place or not.
This is a classic case where locking will be required, please look into optimistic and pessimistic locking

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a secondary table to sync all these record from different devices and have your logic decide which one to discard and which one to save and after deciding on the action, you can delete that entry from the sync table.

---

device_id | attributes (JSON).       | modified_at      | post_id

---

1         | {data: {something: here}} | 8-7-2018 2:30:44 | 4

2         | {data: {something: here}} | 8-7-2018 2:40:44 | 4

---

Now, you can have your code decide which one to keep from the above entries.

Your logic could be based on the date modified or some other important attributes like price(I'm just assuming)

You could also use sockets or something similar (pub|sub), so depending on your action, you can publish the saved record to all the listening devices working on that post, which will update the existing record with the latest entry.

Best,
Pramod